# PHP - update / refine _GET values

Tags: php, get

Let's say i'm in this page:

```
search.php?cat=1&powerf=0&powert=0&kilometragef=10&kilometraget=50&yearf=2009&....
```

and i have all those powerf, kilometraget, etc. input fields and selectboxes in it. How to update selected criterias by clicking a link or a button? I want to return same _GET form but with replaced items (if selected / inputed). Any ideas?

Final variant:

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {

$get = $_GET;
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
if ($key != "update") {
$get[$key] = $value;
}
}

$link = 'search.php?';
$link.= http_build_query($get);

header("Location: http://www.url/$link");
}
```

Comment: Could you rephrase? It isn't clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to make a search system. After i choose my criterias, i get results and i'm in a page which url looks like this:

search.php?cat=1&powerf=0&powert=0&kilomet...

and i have some same select boxes and input fields in it that i had in my search form. Now i want to be able to update my choosed values

Comment: Replace them with what? Give an example.

Comment: It looks a bit strange to me to have to use both post and get in the same time. For me, they kind of kick each other out. Of course, this is something more looks than requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
$get = $_GET;
$get['powerf'] = 'something-else';

$link = 'search.php'
$link.= http_build_query($get);

echo '<a href="', $link, '">Click</a>';
```

Comment: that won't work because i want to keep the old get value and REPLACE some of them with the new ones

Comment: What does that mean? I am replacing one of them, but keeping the rest.

Comment: well, yes, but i don't have $get['powerf'] = 'something-else'; yet. Because there are select fields in the page. One of them defines powerf too

Comment: Then have different links for different options? Or do you want to have a dropdown or something?